# What have I done wrong in solving this trigonometric integral $\int \frac{1}{(9-t^{2})^\frac{3}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

What I did was notice that it is a sqrt in the denominator which indicates to use trig sub. And then noticed it’s of the form $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ so $x = a\sin(\theta)$

So then,
$x = 3\sin(\theta)$

$dx = 3\cos(\theta)dθ$

$\displaystyle\int \frac{3\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ (9-(3\sin(\theta))^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\displaystyle\int \frac{3\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ (9–9\sin^{2}(\theta))^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\frac{3}{9^{\frac{3}{2}}} \displaystyle\int \frac{\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ (1 - \sin^{2}(\theta))^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\frac{3}{9^{\frac{3}{2}}} \displaystyle\int \frac{\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ ( \cos^{2}(\theta) )^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\frac{1}{9} \displaystyle\int \frac{\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ (\cos^{2}(\theta) )^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\frac{1}{9} \displaystyle\int \frac{\cos(\theta)d\theta}{ (\cos^{2}(\theta) )^{\frac{3}{2}} }$

$\frac{1}{9} \displaystyle\int \frac{1}{ (\cos^{2}(\theta)) }$

$\frac{1}{9} \displaystyle\int \sec^{2}(\theta)d\theta$

$\frac{1}{9}[\tan(\theta)]$

Did a triangle and got:

$= \frac{1}{9}\bigg[ \frac{t}{\sqrt{ 9 - t^{2} } }\bigg] + C$

Please help
Thank you

Comment: Drop the annoying  *'s  and* write \sin x , \cos x, \tan x so that things will show nicely. It would also be a good idea to write down the *original* integral...

Comment: alright reposted with the original integral. What 's are you talking about?

Comment: What have you done wrong? Your answer is correct

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct. @yre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $t=3\sin\theta$ we have $\frac{t}{\sqrt{9-t^2}}=\tan\theta$.